# Format Android EditText as HH:MM:SS

Tags: android, android-edittext, date-formatting

I have an edit text in android studio, and I want to get a value for **hours, minutes, and seconds from the user**. How can I start with the edit text saying `00:00:00`, and have the user input numbers, but leave the :'s intact?

**I'd rather not ask the user to enter the semicolons themselves**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MaskedEditText](https://github.com/VicMikhailau/MaskedEditText)

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.vicmikhailau:MaskedEditText:2.0.3'
}
```

---

**add in xml**

```
<com.vicmikhailau.maskededittext.MaskedEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:mask="your_mask" />
```

[image]